# Detect Text files containing specific words using R

Tags: r

I need to scan 100 text files and get filename of the text files containing the specific words "Also" and or "Bread".

I have tried the following script on some text sample files:

```
> myfiles <- list.files("C:\\Documents\\R\\wd\\text")
> myfiles
[1] "111 - Copy (2).txt" "111 - Copy (3).txt" "111 - Copy (4).txt" "111 - Copy (5).txt"
[5] "111 - Copy (6).txt" "111 - Copy.txt"     "111.txt"



> list.files(path= myfiles, pattern = "Also")
character(0)
```

Please help!
Thank you

Comment: Your example won't find anything because none of your filenames have `"Also"` in them. Other than that, it should be fine.

Comment: So "Bread" and "Also" are in the *contents* of the files, but you need to find the filenames of those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern` argument to `list.files` is for matching file *names* containing a specific pattern. Since you want to match on the *content* you'll need to actually read each file and search them. One way to do that is

```
myfiles <- list.files("C:\\Documents\\R\\wd\\text", full.names = TRUE)

Filter(function(file) any(grepl("(Also)|(Bread)", readLines(file, warn = FALSE))),
       myfiles)
```